# Django 1.7 upgrade error: AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-1.7

I am trying to upgrade a project from Django 1.6 to 1.7. I get the following error:

```
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] mod_wsgi (pid=14523): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/users1/k/kisvadim/domains/mathtasks.org/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.get_response(request)
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] __import__(name)
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/mathtasks/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] admin.autodiscover()
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 23, in autodiscover
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 67, in autodiscover_modules
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] self.check_apps_ready()
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
[Thu Oct 09 14:16:41 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

django.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
import django
virtual_env = os.path.expanduser('~/virtualenv/PythonEnv')
activate_this = os.path.join(virtual_env, 'bin/activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'django/mathtasks'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mathtasks.settings'
django.setup()
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error and how to fix it?

UPDATE1:

I replaced:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to:

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

And I get the following error:

```
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] mod_wsgi (pid=17128): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/users1/k/kisvadim/domains/mathtasks.org/django.wsgi'. 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__ 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.get_response(request) 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()) 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] if resolver.urlconf_module is None: 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name) 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] __import__(name) 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/mathtasks/urls.py", line 6, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from utils.views import SniptRegistrationView 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/utils/views.py", line 1, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/registration/backends/default/views.py", line 7, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from registration.views import ActivationView as BaseActivationView 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/registration/views.py", line 11, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from registration.forms import RegistrationForm 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/registration/forms.py", line 159, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 284, in __new__ 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] opts.help_texts, opts.error_messages) 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 184, in fields_for_model 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] opts = model._meta 
[Thu Oct 09 15:06:15 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

UPDATE 2:

I replaced:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

and:

```
models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

And I get the following error:

```
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] No handlers could be found for logger "django.request" 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] mod_wsgi (pid=31421): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/users1/k/kisvadim/domains/mathtasks.org/django.wsgi'. 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__ 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.get_response(request) 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()) 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] if resolver.urlconf_module is None: 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name) 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] __import__(name) 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/mathtasks/urls.py", line 6, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from utils.views import SniptRegistrationView 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/utils/views.py", line 1, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/registration/backends/default/views.py", line 6, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] from registration.models import RegistrationProfile 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/django/mathtasks/registration/models.py", line 9, in <module> 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] User = get_user_model() 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 136, in get_user_model 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] self.check_models_ready() 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] File "/home/users1/k/kisvadim/virtualenv/PythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.") 
[Thu Oct 09 16:10:52 2014] [error] [client 95.79.172.156] AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 91):

see http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.7.html#standalone-scripts

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: The `get_wsgi_application()` solution did not work as my app was already configured as such. but calling `django.setup()` helped.

Comment: This worked out for me. Got the initial error after migrating to Django 1.9.

Comment: Where exactly do you put this? I do not have any standalone scripts that I know of.

Answer (score 74):

I had a similar (the same?) isssue when upgrading to Django 1.7. In may case, it was enough to update the wsgi file: replace

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

with

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Took me hours to stumble upon this. I was also getting { No handlers could be found for logger "django.request" } and this solved my issue immediately. Thanks!!

Comment: I had this only on production, with gunicorn. Works like a charm, now!

Comment: Thanks! Solved problem where I could only run server via: ./manage.py runserver, as opposed to running via gunicorn after Django 1.5 to 1.11 upgrade

Answer (score 22):

I was looking through all these thread to get celery working on windows (with this particular error message) and I just want to emphasize putting

```
import django
django.setup()
```

at the top of your tasks.py file, this is finally what got it working for me.

Answer (score 12):

`INSTALLED_APPS` Had an missing comma in the array, that caused the error for me.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error when I tried to import models from the app's `__init__.py`, which is not possible.

Comment: Not just models, because I had tried to import urls and faced the same issue

Comment: You declaring your models at __init__? weird... you should declare at models... and maybe, just maybe load some models at __init__ if you package must be loaded first.

Comment: I'm not recommending it, I'm saying it causes an error

Answer (score 6):

In configuration uwsgi application file ( like uwsgi.ini ) replace:

```
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
```

on

```
module=django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1):

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a string (that's why you get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'` - it expects a Model) and should be used only on `ForeignKey` declarations:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

If you want to refer to your user model somewhere else you need to use `get_user_model`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when moving to a different PC and forgetting to install `psycopg2` in my venv and when using `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',` in my settings.

Perhaps it can be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

In my case SEcret_key was commented by mistake in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) who are getting this error from shell:

Check that you are executing Django's shell and not Python's shell.

```
python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add one of my sub-applications inside `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basketball',
    'basketball.area',
    'basketball.game',
    'basketball.player',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused when I upgraded celery to 4.x and I had this in my INSTALLED_APPS: `kombu.transport.django`. Removing that resolved the issue. Seems it is mostly caused by some incorrect load of django itself.

Answer (score -3):

Just reinstall Django using the command line, not in Pycharm helped to me.